# How do I retrieve the contents of all the files in a directory in a list each one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, directory

I would like to read the all the files in a directory so I'm doing the following:

```
path = '/thepath/of/the/files/*'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    print file
```

The problem is that when I print the files I don't obtain anything; any idea of how to return all the content of the files in a list per file?

EDIT: I appended the path with an asterisk, this should give you all the files and directories in that path.

Comment: I'm confused, can you explain what's your definition of **content**?

Comment: Is this what you want? `contents=[ii.read() for ii in glob.glob(path)]`

Comment: Content is the stuff that each document of the file has.

Comment: I also tried this one: `content_of_the_docs = [codecs.open('/the/path/of/the/folder,'r','UTF-8').read()]` , but only works with one file, I would like to do it for all the files in the folder.

Comment: @newWithPython is 'opiniones' a string with a valid path?

Comment: a valid path it's just a name it has a reference to the valid path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the comment I posted some time ago, this should work:

`contents=[open(ii).read() for ii in glob.glob(path)]`

or this, if you want a dictionary instead:

`contents={ii : open(ii).read() for ii in glob.glob(path)}`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to open the file, this should work, as long as `path` is a valid path string.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like the following to only get files.

```
import os
import glob

path = '/thepath/of/the/files/*'
files=glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        print file
```

Comment: Still the same, when I print i dont get anything, how can i solve this?

Comment: Let's assume you want to search **/home/newWithPython**. You use "/home/newWithPython/*"
I just tried it and it works fine.

Comment: The problem is not the path, when I run the code I dont get anything at the terminal. I get: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I'm not even getting a file not found exception

Comment: exit code 0 usually means no problems occurred during the execution. Are you sure the path is not empty ? Are you sure the path exists ?

Comment: Yes it exists and have some .txt files (3) i dont know what's happening

Comment: Ohh.. I wrote the path wrong, sorry!. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of unclear, but as I understand it, you'd like to get the contents of all the files in the directory. Try this:

```
# ...
contents = {}
for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        contents[file] = f.readlines()
print contents
```

This creates a dict where the key is the file name, and the value is the contents of the file.

Comment: I'm getting this: `IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/'`

Comment: The thing is i have a folder and I want to retrive the content of each document in that folder. Thanks